# Is every non-recursive set in $\Sigma_1$ complete in $\Sigma_1$ (relatively to many-to-one reductions)?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Most well known sets in $\Sigma_1 \setminus\Delta_0$, such as the
  Halting problem, are *complete* in $\Sigma_1$, relatively to the
  many-to-one reduction. In fact I don't know any example of a (non recursive) set in $\Sigma_1$ that
  is not complete.

Is every set in $\Sigma_1\setminus\Delta$ complete in $\Sigma_1$?

- If so, why the trouble of proving completeness for such problems?
- If not (is there some Ladner-type Theorem?), can anyone give
  natural examples of $\Sigma_1\setminus\Delta_0$ sets that are not complete?

  Of course the question generalizes for other levels of the arithmetic hierarchy.

  I apologize if this question was already answered here, or if the answer is well known.

Answer (score 10):

Not every set in $\Sigma_1\setminus\Delta_1$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete.

For Turing reductions it was known as Post's Problem and resolved by Friedberg and Muchnik around 1957. Interestingly there is still no known *natural* solution to Post's problem. Perhaps the closest is as follows: let $W_{e,s}$ be the $e$th $\Sigma_1$ set in some standard enumeration, as it looks at stage $s$; let $K(j)[s]$ be the prefix free Kolmogorov complexity of $j$ as approximated at stage $s$; and let $A=\bigcup_sA_s$ where the finite sets $A_s$ are uniformly $\Delta_1$ and
$$
A=\{\langle e,n\rangle : \exists s(W_{e,s}\cap A_s=\varnothing\wedge \langle e,n\rangle\in W_{e,s}\wedge \sum_{\langle e,n\rangle\le j\le s}2^{-K(j)[s]}<2^{-(e+2)})\}
$$
Then $A$ is $K$-trivial (which implies it is not $\Sigma_1$-complete) and not $\Delta_1$ ([Downey, Hirschfeldt, Nies, Stephan](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~downey/ccr_2012.pdf)).

For $m$-reductions the problem was already resolved by Post. He constructed a set $A\in \Sigma_1\setminus\Delta_1$ whose complement $B$ contains no infinite $\Delta_1$ set, and showed that such a set $A$ would have to be $m$-incomplete. In standard terminology $A$ is simple and $B$ is immune.

Comment: There are even conjectures and results to the effect that there *cannot* be a natural solution: for example, there is no $e\in\omega$ and computable total $f$ such that (1) for all sets $X$, $X<_TW_e^X<_TX'$, (2) if $X\equiv_TY$ via $\Phi_d$ then $W_e^X\equiv_TW_e^Y$ via $\Phi_{f(d)}$. I believe even more is known, but I can't recall.

Comment: Does your remark on the lack of natural complete sets apply to many-one completeness (mentioned in the OP) as well as Turing completeness?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Omega$ be the [halting probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant), and let $X$ be the set of rational numbers less than $\Omega$.  I think I can reasonably claim that $X$ is a natural set.

Since $\Omega$ is left-c.e., $X$ is $\Sigma^0_1$.  Also, $X$ is non-computable since it's Turing equivalent to $\Omega$.  However, $X$ cannot be many-one complete for $\Sigma^0_1$ sets.  Indeed, no convex set of rationals (or finite union of convex sets of rationals) can be many-one complete for $\Sigma^0_1$ sets.

Suppose $X$ were complete.  Note that $\emptyset'$ is *uniformly* many-one complete: from a $\Sigma^0_1$ index for a set, we can compute an index for its reduction to $\emptyset'$.  Since $X$ is complete, there is a reduction from $\emptyset'$ to $X$, and so by composing these we see that $X$ is uniformly many-one complete (this argument works for any complete set).

Now, we'll make a $\Sigma^0_1$ set $V$, and by a standard argument with the recursion theorem we can assume we already know an $n$ with $V = W_n$.  Using the uniformity, this means we know the index of a computable reduction $f$ from $V$ to $X$.

Begin by computing $f(0), f(1)$ and $f(2)$.  These are rational numbers, and so are arranged in some order.  Without loss of generality, let's assume that $f(0) \le_\mathbb{Q} f(1) \le_\mathbb{Q} f(2)$.  Then enumerate $0$ and $2$ into $V$, but leave $1$ out.  By assumption, this means that $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ are in $X$, but $f(1)$ is not.  But this contradicts the convexity of $X$.

Comment: Nice although I suppose the $ m $-degree of this set depends on the version of $\Omega $ used? Also instead of $\Omega $ we could use $0'$ which is even more natural?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure I've got a construction of m-incomparable versions.  If you mean the real $0.\emptyset'$, that should also work, but again different numberings will give different $m$-degrees.  Also, I'm stumped on whether these are tt-complete.

Comment: Because $\Omega$ itself is not a canonical number, but is only a arbitrarily chosen member of an infinite class of $\Omega$-numbers, sets defined using $\Omega$ will not be natural.

Comment: Well, even Hilbert ' 10th problem has to be encoded to get a subset of $\omega $... which can be done in many ways

Comment: Often, naturalness makes sense only modulo some notion of equivalence. In the context of $m$-equivalence, there is only one reasonable encoding of Hilbert's 10th problem, and it is natural. Not so for (left cuts of) $\Omega$.